# Source Tree branches are not colored correctly

Tags: version-control, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Source Tree for managing my code versions on Bit Bucket. I'm using Mercurial repositories. I have two branches for now, the default and the develop branch. The problem starts when I try to merge the changes from the develop branch into the default branch. Here are the two images of the current tree:

[image: Problematic tree]
[image: Correct tree]

I did some development in develop branch and merged it all to the default branch. now I have some stuff to check in the develop again. When I want to check it in, the tree coloring changes in weird fashion.

The right side picture displays the correct coloring of the tree. The default branch is the oldest and starting branch. The develop is branched out after six commits. I initially commited some stuff there before I decided to do a better job of keeping my versions. The problem is when I change my current active branch to develop (left side image), Source Tree decides to display the develop branch as oldest. If you look at the images, the develop is set next to a violet dot and default is set next to a blue dot, which makes it seem the default was branched out of develop at flow initialization, which is simply not true.

Can anyone explain what is going on here? How could I keep my oldest (default) branch colored as it should be?

Comment: I use TortoiseHg, and the dots always remain the color of the branch it was committed in. Although the history of commits seems ok, this seems to be an issue in SourceTree, but not with Mercurial itself. The tag coloring seems to follow the dots coloring also, which would be ok if the dots were colored correctly.

Comment: Vince, you seem to be correct. I just pushed some new changes to the BitBucket and coloring there seems correct. The question is, how did this pass by the guys at Atlassian, or is it hapening only in my case. I'm considering posting a bug report to see why is this happening. Any more detailed info about the problem is greatly appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of <strike>(colored)</strike> graph, the two screenshots you posted are similar, except for the very top part: "Uncommited changes" is attached to the tip of develop, and the tip of default, respectively.

The left-most branch is the current branch (i.e. the checked-out branch), not the oldest branch. If you think this behaviour should change, the best thing to do is to open an issue on [Atlassian's JIRA for SourceTree](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN) (or [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE) for the Mac version).

Comment: I understand that the leftmost branch is the currently checked out branch. What seems wrong to me, though, is the coloring / position of the lower part of the branch. The thing is, the left side image displays the scenario where I would have the default branch branched out of the develop branch at the sixth point counting from the bottom (sixth check in), which is simply not the case. Quite the opposite, I branched out the develop branch from the default one. I will be posting the bug report later in the day. Regards for info.

Comment: I see what you mean, it seems that I was too quick in writing "In terms of (colored) graph, the two screenshots you posted are similar", which is wrong. I use SourceTree with Git (not Mercurial), and I'm not familiar enough with Mercurial to be certain, but perhaps that lower part of the branch is considered as belonging to both default and develop, since that's their "common history"? That would explain the change in coloring.

Comment: So you're saying you haven't observed such problems on Git repositories? Strange... that would mean something might be wrong only with the Mercurial implementation (or the bridge between Mercurial code and Source Tree). As I said to Vince, BitBucket displays the correct branch coloring. I see your reasoning, but if that is true, it seems very weird. It should at least be colored differently. I'm quite sure that's a bug, though.

Comment: I've actually never paid close attention to the coloring, I'm simply content as long as all my commits are there and the graph is correct.
The behaviour for my Git repos is different however: regardless of the current branch, the left-most branch is always `master` (Git's `default`), and its coloring is consistent all the way down. That would indeed indicate a bug, either in Mercurial, or in SourceTree's Mercurial implementation.

Comment: I have posted a bug report. Thanks for the info.